# Maaneh Lashon - Book

Tags: tefilla, minhag, jewish-books, prayer-book, funeral-burial-levaya

My grandfather used to use this book when he was alive to daven at the cemeteries of his relatives each year.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMNwb.jpg

(The first pages are different but the rest looks exactly the same)
https://ia902604.us.archive.org/0/items/nybc210910/nybc210910.pdf

My mother has been doing the same since that’s why he did.

Few questions:

Is there an English version?
I can’t seem to find the right English translation. I’d like to read the actual English translation and maybe also learn more about the book itself.

I guess Chabad uses this? I found some English from them but I’m not sure it’s the same. (We are not Chabad and I’m not sure if their version is different).

We are modern orthodox. Is this something people use when they visit family? Should my mother maybe say Tehillim instead?

She says certain portions of the book, for example there is a place for father or brother. What would be the right way to use this? What paragraphs do you start with for example?

Thanks.

Comment: Check out the book Mourning in Halacha. It has the prayers for cemetery with English translation along with a discussion of what to do at cemetery.